# I have a php array I'm trying to insert into a database, but the content that gets inserted just says "Array"

Tags: php

As the description says, I'm attempting to send a php array into a database, I know that mysql doesn't understand php so I was wondering how I get the content out of the php array in order to insert it. Right now I have several columns for said table in the database, but would it be easier to insert the data as one big string rather than individually?

Insert.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "salestest";
    
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
var_dump($_POST);
$name = $conn -> real_escape_string($_POST['txtCustomerNameLater']);
$phone = $_POST['txtPhoneLater'];
$email = $_POST['txtEmailLater'];
$ropo = $_POST['txtRopoLater'];
 $address = $_POST['txtAddressLater'];
$sku = $_POST['txtSKULater'];
 $productName = $_POST['txtProductNameLater'];
$quantity = $_POST['txtQuantityLater'];
$retailPrice = $_POST['txtRetailPriceLater'];
$listPvrice = $_POST['txtListPrice555Later'];
$total = $_POST['txtTotalLater'];
$alueCookie = array_values($_COOKIE);
$firstValCookie = $valueCookie[0];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());


$counts = $sku;

foreach($counts as $index=>$dat){
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(customer_name, phone, email, ropo, address, 
  sku, product_name, quantity, retail_price, list_price, total,timestamp, user) 
  values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $name, $phone, $email, $ropo, $address, $sku, $productName, 
$quantity, $retailPrice, $listPrice, $total, $date, $firstValCookie);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();

}




$conn->close();

?>
```

Array of data to insert:

```
array(11) { ["txtCustomerNameLater"]=> string(13) "101 Auto Body" ["txtPhoneLater"]=> string(12) 
"510-524-4857" ["txtEmailLater"]=> string(20) "henrykseng@yahoo.com" ["txtRopoLater"]=> string(4) 
"asdf" ["txtAddressLater"]=> string(55) "101 Auto Body 5327 Jacuzzi St Ste 3A Richmond, CA 94804" 
["txtTotalLater"]=> string(5) "52.84" ["txtSKULater"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "8620843-0423L" 
 [1]=> string(14) "15952187-0053L" } ["txtRetailPriceLater"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "11.75" 
[1]=> string(5) "66.81" } ["txtListPrice555Later"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "7.75" [1]=> 
string(5) "45.09" } ["txtProductNameLater"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(44) "Stone Guard Left Volvo XC 
90 03-14 Rear Door" [1]=> string(34) "Stone Guard Chev/Gmc 3500 DRW Left" } ["submitOrder1"]=> 
string(0) "" }
```

The customer's information goes in as normal, but the product details only say "array" for each column and it's doing an insert for each item in the array, I send out a confirmation email for this product, and i'm not sure how I would catch each insert for the email.

Comment: Where do you use $index and $dat in the foreach loop and what is the purpose of it?

Comment: adding to @manqlele  comment, `$counts = $sku;` assigned sku variable to count and then processing foreach is fine but again you used same variable `$sku` in bind parameters???

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I figured they were anonymous. What would a solution to this be?

Comment: The solution depends on what you are trying to achieve, which I don't know what it is. In you example I don't understand what are you trying to do with this foreach loop, so you can try to remove it and try inserting the query 1 time.

Comment: without the for each loop, I dont think the insert works.